# Importar componentes Vue.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, webpack

estoy trabajando en un proyecto en .NET con MVC y Vue​.js, al momento de querer usar los componentes los tengo que declarar de la siguiente forma:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

import example from './components/example.vue'
import hello from './components/hello.vue'
import equiposcrear from './components/equipos/crear.vue'
import equipos from './components/equipos/index.vue'
import cargardiesel from './components/equipos/cargarDiesel.vue'

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        example,
        equiposcrear,
        equipos,
        cargardiesel
    }
})
```

si lo pongo como

```
Vue.component('equipos', require('./components/equipos/index.vue'));
```

al momento te quererlo usar `<equipos></equipos>` me dice que el componente no está declarado.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Equipos";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div id="app">
    <equipos></equipos>
</div>
```

Así tengo el archivo `webpack.config`

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./Vue/app.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "./Scripts/app.js",
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.min.js'
        }
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.vue$/, loader: 'vue-loader' },
        ],
    }
}
```

Alguien que me puedar orientar?
Gracias

Comment: Mejor pega en tu pregunta __cómo estás definiendo el componente `<equipo>`__. No parece que tu archivo de Webpack sea el problema.

Comment: Es preciso conocer cómo estás declarando el componente "equipos", el cual apunta al archivo *'./components/equipos/index.vue'*.